# Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010 requesting password every time it starts

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have one Exchange 2010 server which is fully updated, the clients are running Outlook 2010 but some users are getting a prompt for credentials every time they open Outlook.

I have checked for common errors like the checked box *Always request authentication*.

I think this happens only with new users that are created in AD and in Exchange and I can't do `gpupdate` - could that be related?

Answer (score 4):

I've had this issue before on a client site, it may be entirely unrelated but I'll post my experiences here.

My first port of call to diagnose it was to open up outlook, leave the credentials request window open and then see where the request for credentials was going to; outlook has a handy tool built in that shows you all the connections it's making. To view it locate the notification area outlook icon in the taskbar (the icons on the right of the screen by the clock, rather than the ones to the left by the start menu) and then ctrl+right-click to bring up a slightly different context menu, in there click Connection Status.

When I did this I found that outlook was trying to make a connection to an public folders on an old exchange server that had been decommisioned and that this was happening because the current public folder was redirecting to the old one. I deleted the public folder and recreated it and voila, no more login prompts.

Of course there are a hundred reasons your outlook clients could be asking for credentials but I do recommend checking the connection status to see where it's pointing to, I found that once I entered the credentials the connection dissapeared in connection status, so that's worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but for some reason it all sorted out when I upgraded my MS Office to Service Pack 2 and I also deleted the stored user name and password with the following command `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr`.

Answer (score 0):

Check control panel- user accounts and select manage your credentials, and look for the Outlook related information. Edit the information to reflect your current password.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but is not that. credentials is empty.

Answer (score 0):

They need to change their user password.  Once they do that, logout and log back in.  That should fix the problem.

Comment: I have changed the password and reboot the client machine, still the same. any ideias  ? I have no more ideias. May be the way that the new computeres are added to the domain ?

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Outlook.

Comment: Already have done that too. I Think that could be a problem with the authentication from the computer to the AD . Have anyone experience something like this ? Another sinthom is that if i put my exchange account NOT in chached mode it does not ask me the password everytime that i startup the outlook. But that is not the solution...

Comment: You say it only happens with new users you've created.  Have you confirmed this?

Comment: Yes, it only Happers in the new users / new installed machinnes... Have anyone have this sythoms ? ´

Answer (score 0):

I would also check to see if the users who are getting prompted are set to use Outlook Anywhere (RPC) and have "On fast networks, connect using HTTP first, then connect using TCP/IP" checked.  This would cause them to be prompted for their password when opening their profile. This setting is found at:

File> Account Settings> Data Files tab> Settings > Connection Tab > Exchange Proxy Settings

Comment: That settings I have checked to the are correct, as they are as another computer that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue definitely related to accounts and not PCs?  ie, if you set up one of the new accounts on another PC with their Outlook/Exchange working fine, do you still get the problem?
Also, windows logs on the effected computers aren't showing anything relevant?

I've seen this happen before, but it was caused by intermittent DNS issues on a badly set up network; the network was re-wired and reconfigured and it solved the problem, so I couldn't give you the exact change that solved it unfortunately!

Comment: so, this morning  I have made some new tests, and I have test my outlook account on one computer that the user says that his outlook does not request credencials, and for my account it request it. So i think this is a config option on the server. Wee have recenty installed updates on Exchange server.  Our network is fine and good configured to.

The DNS issue i think it is not, but sometimes i can´t do gpupdate. Is this relevant ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common complaint.

I could regurgitate this set of posts, but here is a link that helped me solve this in the past: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2010/thread/cd38f3f2-892f-470c-b52e-17b8beeb275e

If one of these steps works for you, please post what solved it.

I also found these:
http://blog.montopolis.com/2010/10/24/outlook-2010-does-not-save-password-with-exchange/
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/481

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but none of this worked for me. I already have go throught that links... It is supposed that outlook when you are inside your company does not ask you any password because he can autenticate automatically

Comment: Yes, Outlook does require a password every time, but in most cases, it gets it from pass-through authentication from when you log in. If you have Microsoft's hosted Exchange, they have a single-sign-on application that has a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

I Had this issue and applied the Office 2010 SP1 - it is a known error with Office 32bit on a 64Bit version of windows 7

Comment: Could you please add some references that agrees with you on that?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thinks to check:

1. Check to see if the time on both the clients and server is synced. If they are out of sync then Kerberos stops working, See the following TechNet article for more details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779260(v=ws.10).aspx
2. Also on the clients check the following file **C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb**. If the "Date modified" hasn't changed in a while then this fault might be caused by a corrupt Group Policy Security Database. Delete **secedit.sdb** on the effected clients and then run **grpupdate /force** from a Command Prompt or reboot the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into Outlook - File - Info - Account Settings - Double click the Exchange Account - More Settings - Security Tab - CHECK the Always Prompt for Logon Credentials - Close Outlook - enter username and password - click on Remember my Credentials - close Outlook and repeat - and don't forget to click on Remember my Credentials.    Go back into More Settings - Security Tab - and REMOVE the check from the Alway Prompt for Logon Credentials.  Close Outlook.
2. Go to Control Panel-User Accounts-Manage your credentials, under Generic Credentials you will see your Outlook Saved Password.  My belief is the password saved in this area is invalid.  Remove the saved password and log on to Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue in our Company - we are working via a proxy server for http/s traffic and after adding the FQDN of our Exchange server into the proxy exclusion list on Chrome. Close outlook reopen and all was working again, this also fixed my Out of Office issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was occurring because of an issue with SharePoint. Once I removed SharePoint from my Outlook profile the password prompt went away.